# active admin confirmation alert before delete action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud, activeadmin

I want to add are you sure alert when delete button in active admin
I follow an answer that it might solve my problem but it link me to this http://localhost:3000/admin/cases?alert=Are+you+sure%3F&method=delete

```
ActiveAdmin.register Case do
permit_params  :user_id,:number,:ship,:finished, :product_ids,:step_ids  , :pt_first_name,:pt_last_name
  index do
    column "ID",:number
    column "Patient first name" do |patient|
      patient.pt_first_name.capitalize
    end
    column "Patient Last name" do |patient|
      patient.pt_last_name.capitalize
    end
  actions defaults: false do |post|
    link_to("Destroy", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
  end
```

Can someone tell me how to do it in index and in show in active admin
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change confirmation message on delete action on show page in active admin rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32645148/change-confirmation-message-on-delete-action-on-show-page-in-active-admin-rails)

Comment: I added  config.clear_action_items! to activeadmin.rb but where to add this?  action_items only: :show  do
    link_to "Delete", { action: :destroy }, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'All grades, uploads and tracks will be deleted with this content.Are you sure you want to delete this Content?' }
  end

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the link_to helper this way:

```
link_to("Destroy", resource_path, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Sure?' })
```

In your example the actual destination of the link is missing. By the way: you don't have to use `config.clear_action_items!`.

You can put something like this above the `permit_params` line:

```
actions :all, :except => [:new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Then only `:index` and `:show` will be availablle. But configure as you wish. Be sure to check the documentation (good stuff over there)

https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html

Good luck.

Comment: I got this error No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/cases", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Have you removed the clear_action_items!, also first try to remove the line with ```actions :all...``` and make sure you spelled the ```link_to``` like I put it..

Comment: I got another error No route matches [DELETE] "/admin/cases"

Comment: It's working now but I am not getting any alert to confirm. It's deleting right away

Comment: What happens if you put the whole `index do` block in comments. Does the confirmation alert show with default acitve admin behaviour? If not I guess the issue is with a missing jquery-ujs.js asset. What javascripts are included? (check with F12)